# Scroll entire html/body when keyboard popsup likewhatsapp

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using html5/javascript/jQuery/css for mobile app development. HTML body contains Header , footer and in middle one div. Footer comprises of one textbox where user can enter inputs. Whenever user touches textbox , keyboard popsup. The problem is html body is not moving up whenever keyboard popsup. How to achieve the same? It should be compatible with all mobile devices( Android, ios, windows).

Here's my html code

```
<body onload="hidebtn()">
    <header class="topBar">

        <ul class="nav nav-tabs row" id="myTab" role="tablist">
            <li class="nav-item col">
                <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true" style="padding-top: 20px; font-size: 14px; cursor: pointer;" onclick="chat()">Chat</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item col">
                <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false" style="padding-top: 20px; font-size: 14px; cursor: pointer;" onclick="ticketStatus()">Incident</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item col">
                <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false" style="padding-top: 20px; font-size: 14px; cursor: pointer;" onclick="ticketStatus()">Service Request</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </header><br><br>
    <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent" style="overflow:hidden;">
        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row h-100">
                    <div id="topButtons" class="card-body" style="padding: 0; margin-top: 12px; height: 80px;"></div>
                    <div id="chatBody" class="card-body anyClass">
                <p class="WC_message_fl"><img class="con_im" src="images\chatrobo.png"></p>
                        <p class="WC_message_f"> Type your Questions & Start chatting </p>
            </br></br>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

<div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab" >
                </br></br>      <p class="WC_message_fl" id='msg_table'></p>
                <div class="container" style="overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:auto;height:84vh;"><div class="row"  id="table"></div>
                </div>

                </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab" >
                    </br></br>  <p class="WC_message_fl" id='msg_sr_table'></p>
                <div class="container" style="overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:auto;height:84vh;"><div class="row" id="sr_table"></div></div>
                </div>

    </div>




        <footer id="footerChtbt" style="position:fixed;bottom:0;right:0;left:0;height: 45px;line-height: 20px;background-color: #ECEFF1;font-size: 0.6rem;border-top: 1px solid #aaa;box-shadow: 0 1px 5px 0 #9B9B9B;">
            <span id="Resp" style="color:blue; position: absolute; z-index: 1000; left: 8vw;"></span>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-10">
                        <input id="query" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder = 'Ask sth...'" onkeyup="pressedkey(event)" style="outline:0;box-shadow:none;font-size:14px;" required />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-2" style="padding: 0; margin-top: 2px;">
                        <img src="images/send_icon.svg" name="submitbtn" onClick="sendbtn()" style="cursor: pointer; width: 40px;">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
```

Comment: This code doesn't render anything can you please put the code in a Jsfiddle or something so that we can understand better ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to detect if the virtual keyboard is present but you don't need to do that.

I could not find your input box in your html so I'll just assume that is has the id 'textInput'

```js
let textInput = $("#textInput")
//When the input box gets focused you just have to scroll it into view
textInput.focusin((event) => {
    var elem = event.currentTarget;
    //scrollIntoViewIfNeeded is non standard but supported in many browsers
    if(elem.scrollIntoViewIfNeeded !== undefined) {
        elem.scrollIntoViewIfNeeded()
    } else if(elem.scrollIntoView !== undefined){
        elem.scrollIntoView()
    } else {
        //Fallback if scrollIntoView is not supported
        var offset = textInput.offset()
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: offset.top,
           scrollLeft: offset.left
        })
    }
})
```

```css
#textInput {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="textInput" type="text">
```